# Calculator in Python with TKinter invalid syntax

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I want to make an calculator with python but when i want  to run it, it says at    `be.bind("<Button-1>", calculate)` at `be` invalid syntax. pls help,
Here´s the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

def calculate(event):
        equation = t.get()
        t.delete(0,END)
        try:
                t.insert(0, eval(equation))
        except:
                t.insert(0, "incorrect input")
top = Tk()

t = Entry(top)

t.grid(row=0,columnspan=3)

b1 = Button(top,text="1")
b1.grid(row=1,column=0)
b2 = Button(top,text="2")
b2.grid(row=1,column=1)
b3 = Button(top,text="3")
b3.grid(row=1,column=2)
b4 = Button(top,text="4")
b4.grid(row=2,column=0)
b5 = Button(top,text="5")
b5.grid(row=2,column=1)
b6 = Button(top,text="6")
b6.grid(row=2,column=2)
b7 = Button(top,text="7")
b7.grid(row=3,column=0)
b8 = Button(top,text="8")
b8.grid(row=3,column=1)
b9 = Button(top,text="9")
b9.grid(row=3,column=2)
b0 = Button(top,text="0")
b0.grid(row=4,column=1)
bp = Button(top,text="+")
bp.grid(row=0,column=3)
bm = Button(top,text="-")
bm.grid(row=1,column=3)
bmu = Button(top,text="*")
bmu.grid(row=2,column=3)
bd = Button(top,text="/")
bd.grid(row=3,column=3)
be = Button(top,text="=")
be.grid(row=4,column=3)
bdel = Button(top,text="DEL")
bdel.grid(row=4,column=2)

b1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"1"))
b2.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"2"))
b3.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"3"))
b4.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"4"))
b5.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"5"))
b6.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"6"))
b7.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"7"))
b8.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"8"))
b9.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"9"))
b0.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"0"))
bp.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"+"))
bm.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"-"))
bmu.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"*"))
bd.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"/")
be.bind("<Button-1>", calculate)
bdel.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.delete(0,END))

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can also use the `command` option of the button instead of using bindings: `b1 = Button(top, text="1", command=lambda: t.insert(END,"1"))`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in this `bd.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"/")` (63th line).
Write:

```
bd.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: t.insert(END,"/"))
```